# chrome.tabs.sendMessage returns a error about a closed port, despite the return true

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I know that this question has already been answered, but none of the previous answers helped me. I am recently in JS and still do not understand the intricacies of all things.

When I try to send a message from the pop-up to the script content tab and get a response to the message, I get an error (below).
Without responding to the message, everything works fine.

Spent a lot of time reading the chrome extensions docs and digging through the forums, but everything I don't try returns me to the error:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
```

I tried to return true and promises, but still marking time. Popup code and content script are below.

```
// popup side
let params = {
    active: true,
    // lastFocusedWindow: true
};
chrome.tabs.query(params, init);
function init(tabs) {
    htmlStates.url = tabs[0].url;
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, htmlStates, (response) => {
        console.log(response);
    })
}
```

```
// content script side
function messageCheck(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    // return true;
    // return Promise.resolve({response: 'received'});
    sendResponse({response: 'some response'})
}
```

Comment: Uncomment the `return true;` and place it after the `sendResponse()`.

Comment: The posted code in its present form is correct so I guess you're looking at an old error in chrome://extensions UI. Press the `clear all` button and actually don't use this UI. Use popup's own devtools instead: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: @wOxxOm, thanks a lot! But this error was shown exactly when inspecting the extension through the built-in chrome devtools. Restarting the browser worked for me. It drives me crazy because I wasted so much time on a phantom error. Apparently, no one is immune from this.

Comment: It can happen if you didn't reload the extension or the web page tab after editing the content script.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to check it there was an error when it was sending the message.

```
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, htmlStates, (response) => {
    if(chrome.runtime.lastError){
        console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError, 'Did not send');
    }else console.log(response);
})
```